# Monitor.pulse Method

Tags: c#

Can anybody shed a bit of light on this piece of code. The step by step working? What i understand id that the critical section of code is locked to be accessed by a single thread at a time.

```
lock (buf)
{
    buf.AddRange(ary);
    Monitor.Pulse(buf);
}
```

PS: Msdn explains pulse as

> Pulse (signal), PulseAll

Sends a signal to one or more waiting threads. The signal notifies a waiting thread that the state of the locked object has changed, and the owner of the lock is ready to release the lock. The waiting thread is placed in the object's ready queue so that it might eventually receive the lock for the object. Once the thread has the lock, it can check the new state of the object to see if the required state has been reached.

Comment: This is a good example of why it's a good coding practice to use helpful variable names, and to comment your code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Monitor class maintains two queues per locking object: a "Ready" queue, and a "Waiting" queue.

```
lock (buf)
```

The current thread is placed at the back of the Ready queue for "buf", and waits its turn to get the lock.

We must assume that you have other threads working with buf, and at least one of them called

```
Monitor.Wait(buf);
```

Monitor would then place that other thread in buf's Waiting queue, where it is stuck.

Now, when the current thread gets the lock, execution continues:

```
Monitor.Pulse(buf);
```

This signals Monitor to take the thread at the front of the Waiting queue, and move it to the back of the Ready queue.  That other thread, which was stuck in the Waiting queue, is now in line to gets its turn for the lock on buf.

At the end of the lock block, Monitor.Exit is automatically called, and the current thread is no longer in buf's Ready or Waiting queue.

It's impossible to say why the Monitor.Pulse call is necessary in the lock statement, without seeing the rest of the code.

**EDIT**

Here's my guess for what is going on:
This could be an implementation of the Producer/Consumer queue pattern.

When consumer threads look at buf and see there are no items available for them to consume, they call Monitor.Wait(buf) and sit in the Waiting queue until told that there are new items to consume.

The code you are showing is when a producer thread adds items to buf.
It then calls Monitor.Pulse(buf) to wake up one of the consumer threads and move that consumer thread to the Ready queue, to wait its turn for a lock on buf.

Comment: Thanks for the useful input ! My understanding has improved by your ans